# Angular mat-table sort not triggered

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

For my table I have the following html:

```
<div *ngIf="test">
 <div *ngIf="sortedData" [ngStyle]="{'height': elmtHeight, 'overflow': 'auto'}">
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

        <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns;">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{column}} </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
            <div *ngFor="let data of element[column]">{{data.data}}</div> 
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following in the component:

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(me.sortedData);
this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = ((item: any, header: string) => {
                                    return item[header][0].data;
                                  });
this.test = true;
```

I even created a stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-27gm6u and there it's working.

But for some reason the sort doesn't get triggered, the `console.log()` will not show in my console. I get no error and no warning.

I hope somebody knows what is wrong.

**EDIT**
I reproduced it in the stackoverflow if it's inside an `*ngIf` it's not working.
Seems it's a bug I posted it on the github https://github.com/angular/components/issues/15966

Comment: I miss the console.log statement inside the stackblitz example

Comment: now it seems to work https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Nkavk9LesXX6QjyhauDqjiyyP0bgu4VL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: My question is does anybody know why it shouldn't be triggered.
This is an exact copy of my project only data is little different.
But in my application this is not being triggered by sorting the header :(

Comment: try to change data and see if still occurs

Comment: I tried the data of the stackblitz to no change.

Comment: Ok I found the problem is in a ngIf if the table is inside an ngIf it's not working.

Comment: Posted stackblitz in bug does not work without *ngIf nethter, so its hardly related to ngIf. AAAnd it does not work for me on stackblitz so how come it works for you?

Comment: It does work just remove the ngIf I changed it so it will work now.

Comment: Your changed version do work now as described.

Comment: @Fjordo now means when?

Comment: I removed the image, because @swoox had resolved his problem. It was only the image of his stackblitz demo ,by the way,